# How to connect a input box to an external database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to connect an email box to an external database for something like an email subscription. I don't really have any code to show but example..

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="50">
```

How would I send what is input and submitted in that box to an external database?

Comment: What do you mean with external database?

Comment: We are not here to teach you what is essentially basic PHP (or basic any-other-language-used-to-build-webpages-dynamically).

Comment: I obviously don't understand how to do it Marc B otherwise I wouldn't ask, not everyone understands php.

Comment: By external database I mean a database on another host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it this way: bind an js event on your input, prevent default actions on this element. execute javascript ajax call to server with your external database, catch the request with php installed there, and then execute functions which will write to external(now local) database. The point is, you must work through 2 servers and 2 databases. this is not very effective. I recommend to move database form external resource to server, on which your php runs.